# Moving window regression on time series with defined starting point each day

Tags: r, regression, data-manipulation

I am trying to fit linear models to a time-series where the regression begins at midnight each day and uses all data until 0600 the following morning (covering a total of 30 hrs). I want to do this for every day in the time-series, and this also needs to be applied by a grouping factor. What I ultimately need is the regression coefficients added to the data frame for the day where the regression started. I am familiar with rolling and window regressions and how to apply functions across groups using dplyr. Where I am struggling is how to code that the regression needs to start at midnight each day. If I were to use a window function, after the first day it would be shifted ahead six hours from midnight and I am not sure how to shift the window back to midnight. Seems like I need to specify a window size and a lag/lead at each iteration but can't visualize how to implement that. Any insight is appreciated.

here is some sample data. I would like to model `dv ~ datetime, by = grp`

```
df <- dplyr::arrange(data.frame(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-09-19 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-09-30 00:00:00"),"hour"), 
grp = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 265), 
dv = rnorm(795)),grp, datetime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that we want each regression to cover 30 rows (except for any stub at the end) and that we should move forward by 24 hours for each regression so that there is one regression per date within grp.

```
ans <- df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    r <- rollapplyr(1:nrow(.), 30, by = 24,
            function(ix) coef(lm(dv ~ datetime, ., subset = ix)), 
            align = "left", partial = TRUE)
    data.frame(date = head(unique(as.Date(.$datetime)), nrow(r)), 
      coef1 = r[, 1], coef2 = r[, 2])
  }) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
> ans
# A tibble: 36 x 4
   grp   date          coef1         coef2
   <chr> <date>        <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 a     2020-09-19  -7698.   0.00000481  
 2 a     2020-09-20  -2048.   0.00000128  
 3 a     2020-09-21    -82.0  0.0000000514
 4 a     2020-09-22    963.  -0.000000602 
 5 a     2020-09-23   2323.  -0.00000145  
 6 a     2020-09-24   5886.  -0.00000368  
 7 a     2020-09-25   7212.  -0.00000450  
 8 a     2020-09-26 -17448.   0.0000109   
 9 a     2020-09-27   1704.  -0.00000106  
10 a     2020-09-28  15731.  -0.00000982  
# ... with 26 more rows
```

### old

After re-reading question I replaced this with the above.
Within group create g which groups the values since the last 6 am and let width be the number of rows since the most recent 6am row.  Then run rollapplyr using the width vector to define the widths to regress over.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)  

ans <- df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    g <- cumsum(format(.$datetime, "%H") == "06")
    width = 1:nrow(.) - match(g, g) + 1
    r <- rollapplyr(1:nrow(.), width, 
            function(ix) coef(lm(dv ~ datetime, ., subset = ix)), 
            partial = TRUE, fill = NA)
    mutate(., coef1 = r[, 1], coef2 = r[, 2])
  }) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
> ans
# A tibble: 795 x 5
   grp   datetime                 dv       coef1      coef2
   <chr> <dttm>                <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 a     2020-09-19 00:00:00 -0.560       -0.560 NA        
 2 a     2020-09-19 01:00:00 -0.506   -24071.     0.0000150
 3 a     2020-09-19 02:00:00 -1.76    265870.    -0.000166 
 4 a     2020-09-19 03:00:00  0.0705  -28577.     0.0000179
 5 a     2020-09-19 04:00:00  1.95   -248499.     0.000155 
 6 a     2020-09-19 05:00:00  0.845  -205918.     0.000129 
 7 a     2020-09-19 06:00:00  0.461        0.461 NA        
 8 a     2020-09-19 07:00:00  0.359    45375.    -0.0000284
 9 a     2020-09-19 08:00:00 -1.40    412619.    -0.000258 
10 a     2020-09-19 09:00:00 -0.446   198902.    -0.000124 
# ... with 785 more rows
```

### Note

Input used

```
set.seed(123)
df <- dplyr::arrange(data.frame(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-09-19 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-09-30 00:00:00"),"hour"), 
grp = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 265), 
dv = rnorm(795)),grp, datetime)
```

Comment: When I apply the updated solution on my actual data I keep getting: `Error in data.frame(date = unique(as.Date(.$datetime)), coef1 = r[, 1],  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6` I explored the 'partial' argument thinking there may be too few data points for a slope leading to NA in some cases? Could this cause the error? The "old solution" runs fine but I think it is applying the regression over different subsets for each row if I am understanding the function correctly.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. It works for me.  Exit R and start it up again so you have a fresh session. Be sure you have the latest versions of dplyr and zoo on CRAN.  Also I am using R 4.1 .  Then copy and paste the input in the Note at the end of the answer into R and then copy and paste the code in the answer.

Comment: I have modified the code to cut down the dates to the number of rows in coef in case that is different for your data even though it is not for the example data.

Comment: SO went down during my attempt to update the answer according to my last comment so I have done it again and you might need to check it over again.

Comment: Update worked perfect. Thanks for the introduction to 'group_modify', I had not seen that before.